# Setting initial zoom (directly writing a dxf)

Tags: dxf

I am trying to set the initial zoom in a dxf file.

I know that lines 12 and 22 set the center of the screen in VPORT table, but how do I set the zoom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DXF tag with group code 40 of the VPORT entity defines the height of viewing area in drawing units.

In the latest DXF reference of R2018 this tag has a group code of 45, but I am sure this is an error in the DXF reference (like many others).

Link to the Autodesk Reference of the [VPORT](http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-8CE7CC87-27BD-4490-89DA-C21F516415A9) entity.

All my knowledge about the VPORT entity is [here](https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/dxfinternals/tables/vport_table.html#vport-table-internals).